# Install datastax cassandra on cloudera cluster

Tags: hadoop, installation, cassandra, cloudera, datastax

I have an existing CDH 5.3 cluster running on Ubuntu server. I would like to install Cassandra on the same nodes and integrate it with the existing Cloudera cluster. I know Cassandra allows BYOH now but I cannot find any guide online to help me accomplish it. Has anyone done this? Do you have any instructions i could follow?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Datastax documentation for [BYOH](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/byoh/byohIntro.html)